# nginx + python + websockets + dynamic endpoints

Tags: python, nginx, networking, websocket

- I have a python script that generates samples of a sin wave in json format...

```bash
python stream_sin_wave.py --channel 20_200_1
```

- Where 20, 200 and 1 are "channel parameters" that allow to define the frequency of the sin wave or the sampling rate...
- In a first moment, the script would only stream the samples to stdout, but I've incorporated `websockets` python module so that the script sets up a websocket server on localhost and I can use another application as client to connect and consume the samples
- This is an example of consuming the samples using `wscat` app as a client:

```bash
> ggm@ggm-nitro5:~$ wscat -c "ws://127.0.0.1:8765"
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
< [{"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.0, "time": 0.0}, {"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.3090169944, "time": 0.05}, {"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.5877852523, "time": 0.1}, {"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.8090169944, "time": 0.15}]
< [{"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.9510565163, "time": 0.2}, {"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 1.0, "time": 0.25}, {"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.9510565163, "time": 0.3}, {"channel": "channel_20_200_1", "frequency": 20, "value": 0.8090169944, "time": 0.35}]
.
.
.
```

- The problem that I want to solve now is that the way it is set up today, I need to decide the channel parameters when calling `stream_sin_wave.py`, and then in the moment I call the client application, it'll only have access to that specific channel configuration
- I'd like it to be setup in a way that the channel parameters can be decided by the client app, something like this:

  - `wscat -c "ws://127.0.0.1:8765/20_200_1"` or this `wscat -c "ws://127.0.0.1:8765/40_400_4"` where the endpoints `20_200_1` or `40_400_4` are the channel parameters that would then represent a new evocation of the sample producer script with the respective channel parameters, like: `python stream_sin_wave.py --channel 20_200_1` and `python stream_sin_wave.py --channel 40_400_4`
- Any endpoint is valid and represents a different channel configuration that should be evoked - that is: a new webserver socket should be created on my localhost.

  - This is what I refer to as "dynamic endpoints" in the title
- As this is just a personal project, right now I'm not worried about scalability/performance/safety
- I believe that this is doable with an nginx setup, but I'm completely noob and need help.

  - Is it possible to set it up like I'm saying using nginx + python script?
  - How would the rough structure of the nginx file look like?

Comment: Please ask an actual question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.